# Facing problem in running command prompt commands from java

Tags: java, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to run two cmd commands from java but it seems second command is not running.
Actually i have integrated snowflake with my java program so i am trying internal stage loading. SO for that i have to run put command in order to put my file to internal stage from local file system.for that i need to run 2 commands in my cmd through java.

1)snowsql // for logging into snowsql
2)put command //to put file from local system to internal stage.

i am adding my code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class cmdconnect {





    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, NullPointerException { 
        ProcessBuilder pb =new ProcessBuilder();
        String filpath= "C:\\Users\\Ohr_id\\Desktop\\File_2.csv @int_stage1;";
        
        File path=new File("C:\\Users\\\\Desktop\\File_2.csv @int_stage1;"); 
      
String pt="put file:///";
    
        String res=pt+path;
        System.out.println(res);
                pb.command("cmd.exe", "/c"," snowsql && "+res+"");
      File dir = new File("C:\\Users\\OHR_ID\\Desktop");
       pb.directory(dir);
       Process q= pb.start();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(q.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            int i=0;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                System.out.println(i++);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, better aligned code makes it more easy for users to look and answer your question. Otherwise, most of the times unaligned code are neglected. Personal experience.

Comment: The Snowflake JDBC driver supports the PUT command, so is there a reason you want to call a command line SnowSQL through Java?

Comment: @GregPavlik i just need a way to load my file from local machine to internal stage through java and from there to a snowflake table ...so like can you help with a java code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, you should be able to use the PUT command directly through the JDBC driver. This will be more stable and performant than using Java to call SnowSQL via command line.

Here is a minimal code block you can use to test it:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String accountURL = "my-account.my-region.snowflakecomputing.com";
        
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("user", "my_user");
        props.put("password", "XXXXX");
        
        try {
            Connection con;
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:snowflake://" + accountURL, props);
            PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("put file://c:\\temp\\data\\mydata.csv @TEST.PUBLIC.FOO");
            ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
}
```